# How do I convert definition typescript to json?

Tags: json, typescript

I want the contents of d.ts files to converted to json format i.e. I want the skeleton of functions in d.ts files to be shown in json or as an abstract syntax tree. I want to know how to proceed in order to achieve this. In a nutshell, I just want the existence of that particular function to be shown in the json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically use the typescript compiler api / Program to get a `SourceFile` and the use `ts.forEachChild` to visit all of its children.

## More

Docs : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/overview/ast/ast-tip-children

Comment: Could you give a bit more specific example please @basarat? The links do not work anymore.

Comment: Updated the link 